# Как сделать пагинацию в виде квадратов в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет. Я решил попробовать сделать как на некоторых сайтах пагинацию в виде квадратов, чтобы в зависимости от того на какой стадии заказа продукта находишся синими были прямоугольники, `если на первой то 1 синий,а если на второй то 2 синих`.И чтобы менялся контент блока тоже в зависимости на какой стадии. Мне нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку переходило к следующему блоку и загорался синим один прямоугольник. Можете показать как это сделать?

```css
p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <!-- начальный блок -->
  <div class="content1">
    <input type="text" name="" id="">
    <input type="text" name="" id="">
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
  <!-- второй блок -->
  <div class="content2 hidden">
    <input type="text" name="" id="">
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
  <!-- третий блок -->
  <div class="content3 hidden">
    <p>CONGRADULATION!!!</p>
    <button>CLOSE</button>
  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <p class="active"></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var boxArray = document.getElementById("boxes").getElementsByTagName("p");
var contentEl = document.getElementById("content");
var emailEl = document.createElement('input');

var active_class_name = "active";
var hidden_class_name = "hidden";

function handleIt() {
  for ( var counter = 1; counter < 3; counter++ ) {
    if ( !boxArray[counter].classList.contains(active_class_name) ) {
      boxArray[counter].classList.add(active_class_name); //закрашиваем
      
      if ( counter === 1 ){
        contentEl.removeChild(document.getElementById("login"));
        contentEl.removeChild(document.getElementById("password"));
        
        emailEl.setAttribute("input","text");
    emailEl.setAttribute("id","email");
    emailEl.setAttribute("placeholder","Email");

    contentEl.insertBefore(emailEl, contentEl.childNodes[0]);
      }
      
   if ( counter === 2 ) { // если обрабатывается последний box
        contentEl.removeChild(document.getElementById("email"));

    /*вариант 1 : добавляется класс с "display: none;"*/
    document.getElementById("myButton").classList.add(hidden_class_name);
    //вариант 2 : в теге добавляется "style="visibility: hidden;" */
    //document.getElementById("myButton").buttonEl.style.visibility = "hidden";
    //как вам лучше - сами решайте :)

    alert("We will send u info soon");
      }
   break;
     } 
 }
}
```

```css
p{
 width: 100px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: gray;
 display: inline-block;
}

.active{
 background-color: blue;
}

.hidden{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div id = "content" class="content">
  <input type="text" id="login" placeholder="Login">
  <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button id="myButton" onclick="handleIt()">Click It</button>
 </div>

 <div class="center">
  <div id="boxes" class="blocks">
   <p class="active">Filling</p>
   <p>Email</p>
   <p>Finish</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

На `IE9` не сработает. Кроссбраузерная замена "add" [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp).

Comment: Спасибо!А как сделать чтобы контент менялся ещо?

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov, в каких обстоятельствах он должен меняться? В зависимости от чего? Опишите, как это должно происходить

Comment: Если светится один то отображается  class=content1 если 2  то class="content2", а если 3 то class="content3".И при этом может отображаться  только один контент.

Comment: И как сделать чтобы когда доходит о последнего элемента масива(последней страницы) пропадала кнопка?

P.S. извините за большое количество вопросов.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov , исправлено. Смотрите ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ но самое для меня сложно я так и не понял как реализовать чтобы  вместо разных бордеров выводился разный контент.Допустим что если три div с классами `content1`,`content2`,`content3`(как в вопросе).Я хочу это реализовать как форму регистрации.Пользователь сначала вводит логин и пароль потом жмет кнопку `next` и у него вместо двух `input` только один с тем куда email ввести,а на третей просто сообщение что email выслан. Еще раз извините за кол-во вопросов я наверное совсем глупый :)

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov. Исправил. Получили то, что нужно?

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov ,  о валидации данных сами позаботитесь)

Comment: Спасибо!Очень помогло!

Comment: А можно сделать чтобы оно не создавало новый `input`,а просто показывало тот который уже есть но имеет `display=none`?У меня просто уже есть блоки готовые(сверстанные).Чтобы второй элемент заменят первый а третий заменит второй.